# OpenCv & EmguCv equavalent method?

Tags: opencv, emgucv

**As berak said in the comments, it seems this code is deprecated**

In Opencv there is a method "cvmget", the sample usage is:

```
bool niceHomography(const CvMat * H)
{
  const double det = cvmGet(H, 0, 0) * cvmGet(H, 1, 1) - cvmGet(H, 1, 0) * cvmGet(H, 0, 1);
  if (det < 0)
    return false;

  const double N1 = sqrt(cvmGet(H, 0, 0) * cvmGet(H, 0, 0) + cvmGet(H, 1, 0) * cvmGet(H, 1, 0));
  if (N1 > 4 || N1 < 0.1)
    return false;

  const double N2 = sqrt(cvmGet(H, 0, 1) * cvmGet(H, 0, 1) + cvmGet(H, 1, 1) * cvmGet(H, 1, 1));
  if (N2 > 4 || N2 < 0.1)
    return false;

  const double N3 = sqrt(cvmGet(H, 2, 0) * cvmGet(H, 2, 0) + cvmGet(H, 2, 1) * cvmGet(H, 2, 1));
  if (N3 > 0.002)
    return false;

  return true;
}
```

is there any method in like `cvmget` in EmguCV?

Comment: well, that is code from the last decade. avoid it.

Comment: @berak, why did you votedown?

Comment: because anything related to the deprecated c-api is no more vaild in 2015. you should not use it, and noobs seeing this should not be led astray. (nothing against you, btw.)

Comment: Im not a c programmer or didnt know anything about cvmget and depricated c-apis, I just had a above code and wanted the EmguCv method, and such a lame and non-constructive excuse to vote down.

Comment: you don't seem to be interested in opencv development at all, more trying to defend the outdated approach emgu is built upon. do you vaguely understand the impact of [this](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/3468) ? emgu users won't be able to use haarcascades from now on. (or will have to use an outdated version of opencv)

Comment: hey, in the end, there's something i want from you: change your way. as an avid emgu user, use your impact to make them update their api to the more current c++ one. get involved, instead of defending the old and wrong.

Comment: SttackOverflow is a place for Questions and answers, I asked my question and got my answer, I didn't offer anyone to use my method, I just wanted a emgucv version of http://answers.opencv.org/question/2588/check-if-homography-is-good, but you didnt see question at all, you just saw the **cvmget** (or what ever) and told to yourself, "yea, a dumb deprecated question, lets give vote-down to the question and the answer", I saw your profile with 1400 vote-downs, it is so so easy to give vote-downs without solutions, next time instead of that, came up with a solution like GeorgeChond did.

Comment: I updated my question to let other people know that the code is deprectaed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cvmget` function returns the element of the single channel array. This function is a fast replacement for `GetReal2D`

In EmguCV you can use the `cvGetReal2D` method of the `CvInvoke` class

So, the code in the link you provided should be like:

```
    bool niceHomography(Image<Gray, byte> H)
    {
        double det = CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(H, 0, 0) * CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(H, 1, 1) - CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(H, 1, 0) * CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(H, 0, 1);
        if (det < 0)
            return false;

        double N1 = Math.Sqrt(CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(H, 0, 0) * CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(H, 0, 0) + CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(H, 1, 0) * CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(H, 1, 0));
        if (N1 > 4 || N1 < 0.1)
            return false;

        double N2 = Math.Sqrt(CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(H, 0, 1) * CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(H, 0, 1) + CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(H, 1, 1) * CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(H, 1, 1));
        if (N2 > 4 || N2 < 0.1)
            return false;

        double N3 = Math.Sqrt(CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(H, 2, 0) * CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(H, 2, 0) + CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(H, 2, 1) * CvInvoke.cvGetReal2D(H, 2, 1));
        if (N3 > 0.002)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

PS. Be sure that your array(Image) has just one channel(Grayscale) otherwise a runtime error will be raised. If your array has multiple channels use the `cvGet2D` method instead.

OpenCV Documentation: [mGet](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#mget)

Comment: sad story about emgu is, that it's still mostly using deprecated c-api structures/functions

Comment: Oh, are `cvGetReal*D` and `cvGet*D` deprecated?

Comment: again, as of the c++ based *official* version, yes. they are trying to get rid of IplImage and all retated things since 2010 already.

Comment: So what should I use instead of them?

Comment: since you can't change the underlying implementation, just take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: I was talking about the OpenCV functions.
Well, I am a .NET guy so I didn't know it. :) 

Thanks

Comment: @berak  Emgu.CV has this rather strange comment in its Mat class "/// The equivalent of cv::Mat, should only be used if you know what you are doing.
   /// In most case you should use the Matrix class instead". The Matrix class is the equivalent of a cvMat which is of deprecated, and therefore if you knew what you were doing you wouldn't use that.

Comment: I used George function for HoographyMatrix and worked well, Nice work dude