# Matching image and determine best match using SURF

Tags: c#, image, opencv, emgucv, surf

I have been trying to use the EMGU Example SURFFeature to determine if an image is in a collection of images. But I am having problems understanding how to determine if a match was found.

.........Original image ..............................Scene_1 (match).........................Scene_2 (no match)

[image]...................
[image]...................
[image]

I have been looking at the documentation and spent hours looking for a possible solution, on how to determine if the images are the same.
As you can see in the following pics, a match is found for both.

[image] [image]

Its clear that the one I'm trying to find gets more matches (lines connecting) but how do I check this in the code?

**Question: How do I filter out the good match?**

My goal is to be able to compare an input Image (capture from webcam) with a collection of images in a database. but before I can save all images to the DB I need to know what Values I can compare the input to. (e.g. save the objectKeypoints in the DB)

Here is my sample code (the matching part):

```
private void match_test()
{
    long matchTime;
    using (Mat modelImage = CvInvoke.Imread(@"images\input.jpg", LoadImageType.Grayscale))
    using (Mat observedImage = CvInvoke.Imread(@"images\2.jpg", LoadImageType.Grayscale))
    {
        Mat result = DrawMatches.Draw(modelImage, observedImage, out matchTime);
        //ImageViewer.Show(result, String.Format("Matched using {0} in {1} milliseconds", CudaInvoke.HasCuda ? "GPU" : "CPU", matchTime));
        ib_output.Image = result;
        label7.Text = String.Format("Matched using {0} in {1} milliseconds", CudaInvoke.HasCuda ? "GPU" : "CPU", matchTime);
     }
}

public static void FindMatch(Mat modelImage, Mat observedImage, out long matchTime, out VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints, out VectorOfKeyPoint observedKeyPoints, VectorOfVectorOfDMatch matches, out Mat mask, out Mat homography)
{
    int k = 2;
    double uniquenessThreshold = 0.9;
    double hessianThresh = 800;

    Stopwatch watch;
    homography = null;

    modelKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
    observedKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();

    using (UMat uModelImage = modelImage.ToUMat(AccessType.Read))
    using (UMat uObservedImage = observedImage.ToUMat(AccessType.Read))
    {
        SURF surfCPU = new SURF(hessianThresh);
        //extract features from the object image
        UMat modelDescriptors = new UMat();
        surfCPU.DetectAndCompute(uModelImage, null, modelKeyPoints, modelDescriptors, false);

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        // extract features from the observed image
        UMat observedDescriptors = new UMat();
        surfCPU.DetectAndCompute(uObservedImage, null, observedKeyPoints, observedDescriptors, false);

        //Match the two SURF descriptors
        BFMatcher matcher = new BFMatcher(DistanceType.L2);
        matcher.Add(modelDescriptors);

        matcher.KnnMatch(observedDescriptors, matches, k, null);

        mask = new Mat(matches.Size, 1, DepthType.Cv8U, 1);
        mask.SetTo(new MCvScalar(255));

        Features2DToolbox.VoteForUniqueness(matches, uniquenessThreshold, mask);
        int nonZeroCount = CvInvoke.CountNonZero(mask);

        if (nonZeroCount >= 4)
        {
            nonZeroCount = Features2DToolbox.VoteForSizeAndOrientation(modelKeyPoints, observedKeyPoints,
               matches, mask, 1.5, 20);

            if (nonZeroCount >= 4)
                homography = Features2DToolbox.GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures(modelKeyPoints,
                   observedKeyPoints, matches, mask, 2);
        }

        watch.Stop();
    }

    matchTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

I really have the feeling I'm not far from the solution.. hope someone can help me out

Comment: if you can take better input pictures, this approach should probably work well.

Comment: The approach works sort of.. But my question still stands. I am looking for a way to measure if there was a good match or if a match was bad. By eye it seems there must be an obvious solution i am missing.

Comment: Check [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/2588/check-if-homography-is-good/). It tells you if the homography is good, i.e. if you have a good match. Could be a good starting point. Or you can wrap one image on the other, and check for absolute difference of pixel intensities, or the like.

Comment: Thanks this did help. and after 5 checks it seems to work nicely. But beware: I am using Emgu 3.0 (This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596981/opencv-emgucv-equavalent-method) helped me with the port. Also I had to copy my `homography` Mat to a new `Image<Gray,Byte>` or it would crash.

Comment: Ok good ;D I'm not familiar with C# wrappers

Comment: unfortunately I still get a lot of false matches..

Comment: You could try comparing the coordinates of the matches (match 1 on img1 with match 1 on img2) and see how closely they lie over each other to get more information on the quality of the matches.

Comment: maybe try what's suggested in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569386/opencv-filtering-orb-matches

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On exit from `Features2DToolbox.GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures`, the `mask` matrix [is updated to have zeros](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/html/b5090d13-9a90-589d-ca46-a3aff6786004.htm) where matches are outliers (i.e., don't correspond well under the computed homography). Therefore, calling `CountNonZero` again on `mask` should give an indication of match quality.

I see you're wanting to classify matches as "good" or "bad" rather than just compare multiple matches against a single image; from the examples in your question it looks like maybe a reasonable threshold would be 1/4 the keypoints found in the input image. You might want an absolute minimum as well, on the grounds that you can't really consider something a good match without a certain quantity of evidence. So, e.g., something like

```
bool FindMatch(...) {
    bool goodMatch = false;
    // ...
    homography = Features2DToolbox.GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures(...);
    int nInliers = CvInvoke.CountNonZero(mask);
    goodMatch = nInliers >= 10 && nInliers >= observedKeyPoints.size()/4;
    // ...
    return goodMatch;
}
```

where on branches that don't get as far as computing `homography` of course `goodMatch` just stays false as it was initialized. The numbers 10 and 1/4 are kinda arbitrary and will depend on your application.

(Warning: the above is entirely derived from reading the docs; I haven't actually tried it.)

Comment: I see I got a downvote for this; if whoever downvoted it happens to be reading this comment, I'd be interested to know what you found unsatisfactory so that I can improve it if possible.

Comment: Well I didn't. Thanks alot for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome. I hope it does turn out to be helpful.